# Is it possible to combine two u-tests to get strictly greater than alternative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

When applying the u-test we can have the null hypotheses $a<b$, $a=b$, and $a>b$ which leads to the alternative hypotheses $a\geq b$, $a\neq b$, and $a \leq b$, respectively (at least using scipy's mannwhitneyu function).

If I want to conclude that $a<b$, I was thinking it was possible to run the test with both null hypotheses $a=b$ and $a>b$. If both are rejected we 'know' that $a\neq b$ and $a \leq b$ which logically leads to $a<b$. Yet, I do not have sufficient knowledge to determine if this rationale is valid. I have a suspicion that it is a logical fallacy as we are working with probabilities.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why not just do the one-sided hypothesis test once?

Comment: The scipy implementation[1] only allows for testing less than and not less than equal. I can therefore not determine if the one is strictly greater. 
Other than that, it is also more because I am interested in the answer.

And thank you :-)

[1] https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

Comment: you have just used the equal sign in the wrong place :) $a \geq b$ is the null hypothesis, and $a < b$ is the alternative hypothesis, so as Dave says, you only need a single test. But you logic is not off, it is applied in slightly other situtations. You may want to read about the concept of TOST-procedure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test

Comment: Oh, fair enough. Then it is the description on scipy that confused me as they state: "‘less’: the distribution underlying x is stochastically less than the distribution underlying y, i.e. F(u) > G(u) for all u." I may have wrongly assumed F(u) > G(u) to be the null hypothesis. 

But interesting, I'll look into that :-)
And thanks for the very quick and precise answers.